# image is cropped inside the image view

Tags: java, image, android-studio, imageview

I'm trying to load an image into an image view:
[image]

but the image is cropped inside the image view:

[image]

```
 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@mipmap/icona_animal_app" />
```

why does this thing happen? how can i solve?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing android:scaleType="centerCrop" to android:scaleType="fitCenter"

Comment: I've tried with all the values of the attribute "scaleType" but nothing works

Answer (score 0):

According to your screenshot, ImageView has rounded corners:
[image]

So I assume there is another code affecting that view which causes cropping and rounded corners.